# Android: Suppress Warning on method call

Tags: java, android, permissions, lint, suppress-warnings

I'm trying to do a method that checks for android permissions. But when I call it I have a Missing Permission warning.

Here is a simplification of my code:

```
public void lintTestMethod(){
    if(isPermissionGranted()) {
        requiresLocationPermission();
    }
}

public boolean isPermissionGranted(){
    return true;
}

@RequiresPermission(anyOf = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION})
public void requiresLocationPermission(){

}
```

I tried adding:

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
public boolean isPermissionGranted(){
    return true;
}
```

But it's not working (I also tried using SuppressWarning).

Ideally, I would like to not have to modify the lintTestMethod method.

Does anyone have an idea on how to deal with that ?

Comment: This is not clear where you are adding suppress annotation

Comment: Sorry, I updated the name of the method call. It should be more clear now.

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround to my problem by reading the lint code checking the permissions ([Code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/SupportAnnotationDetector.java)). The solution is to name my method called 'isPermissionGranted' : 'check*Permission'. It's not really the solution I was looking for but it works. If anyone has a better way to do it I'm still interested.

Here is the interesting part of the code:

```
String name = node.astName().astValue();
if ((name.startsWith("check") || name.startsWith("enforce")) && name.endsWith("Permission")) {
      mChecksPermission = true;
      mDone = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You place suppression in wrong place:

Single statement suppression:

```
public void lintTestMethod(){
        if(isPermissionGranted()) {
            //noinspection MissingPermission
            requiresLocationPermission();
        }
    }
```

Method range suppression:

```
@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
public void lintTestMethod(){
    if(isPermissionGranted()) {
        requiresLocationPermission();
    }
}
```

It can be done using Android Studio quick fix menu.

Answer (score -3):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

**Add this in your AndroidManifest.xml file.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not the problem the permissions are present in my manifest :s